# LINEST coefficients are different from graph trendline

Tags: excel

I have two tables and I'm running second order LINEST function for both.

Both tables can be perfectly fit by second order polynomial trendline but for some reason for the second table LINEST returns invalid results which don't match the trendline coefficients.

```
     A    B
--+------------          
1 |   1   6          =LINEST(B1:B9,A1:A9^{1,2},FALSE,TRUE)
2 |   2  24          5.073529412 2.161764706 0
3 |   3  52          Same as graph trendline
4 |   4  90
5 |   5 138
6 |   6 196
7 |   7 264
8 |   8 342
9 |   9 430


      A      B
--+------------          
1 |  0.60   0.215          =LINEST(B19:B27,A19:A27^{1,2},FALSE,TRUE)
2 |  0.75   0.115          0.302122317 -0.190784118 0
3 |  0.90   0.063          
4 |  1.05   0.053          Graph trendline
5 |  1.20   0.097          1.0641 2.1013 1.0914
6 |  1.35   0.194
7 |  1.50   0.341
8 |  1.65   0.528
9 |  1.80   0.749
```

[image]

Comment: You should be using TRUE not FALSE for the const argument.

Comment: @Rory That's correct. Thanks! Can you, please, explain why does FALSE works with the first table but not with the second?

Comment: It looks like your first curve would naturally have crossed the Y axis at or around 0, which is basically what that argument forces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm re-posting Rory's comment to close the question.*

The invalid results are due to the third parameter being set to FALSE. This forces y-intercept (AKA **b** in y=mx+b) to be zero.

In the first case the trend line is described by an equation with b equal to zero and the function worked correctly by accident.